# How can I pass std::cin as an argument for a function?

Tags: c++

I've searched for answers on stackoverflow and am simply not getting it. A well-explained answer would be amazing.

Here's my **incomplete** code for a password validator. I ask for user input and then run it through a series of boolean functions to decide whether it meets the strong password criteria.

If you find any other errors(which I'm sure there is), please let me know. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>

//DECLARING GLOBAL VARIABLES
bool isLong;
bool hasDigits;
bool hasAlphabets;
bool hasSpecial;

//FUNCTION TO CHECK IF PASSWORD IS LONG ENOUGH
 bool  checklen(std::string x)
{
    if (x.length() > 8)
    {
        isLong = true;
    }
    else if (x.length() < 8)
    {
        isLong = false;
    }
    return isLong;
}

//FUNCTION TO CHECK IF PASSWORD HAS DIGITS
bool checkdigits(std::string x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(x[i]))
        {
            hasDigits = true;
        }

        else if (not isdigit(x[i]))
        {
            hasDigits = false;
        }
    }
    return hasDigits;
}

//FUNCTION TO CHECK IF PASSWORD HAS ALPHABETS
bool checkalphabets(std::string x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(x[i]))
        {
            hasAlphabets = true;
        }

        else if (not isalpha(x[i]))
        {
            hasAlphabets = false;
        }
    }
    return hasAlphabets;
}

//MAIN FUNCTION THAT RUNS THE VALIDATION AND HANDLES LOGIC
int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter new password: ";
    std::string password{};
    std::cin >> password;

    checklen(password);                  //trying pass the stored cin value as argument.
    checkdigits(password);              //trying to pass the stored cin value as argument.
    checkalphabets(password);          //trying to pass the stored cin value as argument.

                                                                //the functions literally use "password" as a string instead of the stored user input.

    if (isLong = true)
    {
        if (hasDigits = true)
        {
            if (hasAlphabets = true)
            {
                std::cout << "Your password is strong";
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your password is still weak";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't say anything about whether your program works or not.

Comment: `if (isLong = true)` assigns isLong to true, and then always returns true. Try `if (isLong == true)` (and repeat for the others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool isLong(std::string x)
{
    return x.length() > 8;
}

bool hasDigits(std::string x)
{
  return std::any_of(x.begin(), x.end(), ::isdigit);
}

bool hasAlpha(std::string x)
{
  return std::any_of(x.begin(), x.end(), ::isalpha);
}

bool isStrong(std::string x)
{
  return isLong(x) and hasDigits(x) and hasAlpha(x);
}

int main()
{
  std::string password;
    std::cout << "enter new password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    if (isStrong(password))
      std::cout << "Your password is strong";
    else
      std::cout << "Your password is weak";

    return 0;
}
```

I assume by

> If you find any other errors(which I'm sure there is), please let me
>   know. Thanks!

you want to find the most 'efficient' program.

1. The most important error was that you used one equality sign instead
   of two. This meant that you were simply assigning a value to a
   variable in the `if` statements, not checking for equality.
2. Your `checklen` function returns an uninitialised `boolean` if
   the length of the password is exactly `8`.
3. Your `checkdigits` function has a logic error. The
   return value depends on the last character checked - not the whole
   string. If the last character was a digit, it would return `true`,
   else it would return `false`, not taking in account the whole
   string.
4. The same logic error as above was also in the `checkalphabets`
   function.
5. There is no need to include an empty initialiser list for the declaration of a `std::string`.
6. The nesting of `if` loops is not necessary as you can simply use `&&` operators.
7. Your program does not output "Your password is still weak" in the case where the password has no digits and is not alphabetical. It only outputs the above if the password is not long enough.
8. Global variable use is unnecessary in the program and is frowned upon when dealing with best programming practices. They are available to all functions, classes - however, if you were to define a variable of the same name, there would be a redeclaration error. (This is just one problem when using global variables.)

The code I posted above is what I would consider "optimal". It uses built-in functions to reduce code complexity and is much more consider.

If you are new to programming (which I will assume), I would recommend you try 'dry running' your code as this will help you identify the logic errors.

The syntax error of the equality signs should be picked up by a good compiler. (Or rather, logic error, as the syntax is 'valid' but 99% of the time is not what is intended.)

Inefficiencies in the program code can be reduced with experience (such as the nested `if` loops).

Comment: No problem, everyone is new to programming at some stage. If this helped, please consider marking the answer as accepted and upvoting.

Comment: I would recommend you go over each issue and make sure you understand what the issue is and modify your program (the program I wrote is 'optimal', but  you won't learn too much from it.) This way you can develop the program yourself and remember the errors so to improve your programming skill.

If you need any clarifications, don't hesitate to reply to this comment.

Comment: I am already on it. I don't understand half things you mentioned. But I compiled and it works. I'm going to analyze the whole thing and try to understand what you did. Maybe I'll post my completed validator here that prints a message for uppercase and lowercase as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I see. How new are you to C++ or programming in general? The best way to learn C++ is through a good book. However, I believe you are new to programming, and so may I suggest you instead try a programming language such as Python? Unless you are taking a course in university or online, if you are self-learning Python is the way to go. You will be much more engaged with programming programs that are actually 'useful' in less code such as web scraping, games with Pygame, etc. C++ is lower-level, so you'll have to deal with funkier syntax, memory allocation issues (though in C++11 not an issue.)

Comment: I have been programming for less than two months now. I did begin with python. switched to c++ three weeks ago. It's extremely hard but I thrive more on challenge. Python tends to bore me. I didn't master it or anything(created tic-tac-toe, snake and Blackjack and that's it). I am more engaged with c++ and I like that I have to understand deeper things to write even a simpler program.

Comment: However, if you have any tips on books, courses or projects that I can build to better the learning in C++ that would be AMAZING.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass std::cin as an argument for a function?

`std::cin` is an `std::istream`. Thus, the way to pass it to a function is like this:

```
void function(std::istream& stream) {
    // implmentation...
}
```

**Note:** I believe you can't pass `std::istream`s by value. You must pass it by reference.

Then you call it like this:

```
function(std::cin);
```

Please note that you have other bugs in your program explained better in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58850127/10957435). But that's how you generally pass `std::cin` to a function.

Comment: You are correct, but I think OP is actually asking the wrong question. The program does not need to pass cin as a function - it just doesn't work because the wrong number of equality signs were used for the if statements.

Comment: Fair enough. I simply tried to answer the question in the title. I admittedly didn't really read the code too deep. If you believe you can do better, please feel free to create an answer. If not, I will probably add that in when I feel up to it.